# How to fix the error in logcat related with FATAl activity and audioFlinger

Tags: android-studio

I'm new to android world.I try to build a **real time graph** but there is no error with build and sync but their is an error with log cat.I don't know how to solve it.

This is my **AndroidManifest** code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

this is my **mainActivity.java**

pa

```
ckage com.example.nadeesha.sobiga;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.Legend;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.YAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RelativeLayout mainLayout;
    private LineChart mChart;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//        mainLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        //create line Chart
        mChart= new LineChart(this);
        //add to main layout
        mainLayout.addView(mChart);
        //customize line chart
        mChart.setDescription("");
        mChart.setNoDataTextDescription("No Data at the moment");

        //enable value highlighting
        //Set this to true on your Chart to allow highlighting per dragging over the chart surface when it is fully zoomed out. Default: true
        mChart.setHighlightPerDragEnabled(true);

        // enable touch gestures
        //Allows to enable/disable all possible touch-interactions with the chart.
        mChart.setTouchEnabled(true);

        // Enables/disables dragging (panning) for the chart
        mChart.setDragEnabled(true);

        // Enables/disables scaling for the chart on both axes.
        mChart.setScaleEnabled(true);

        // enough to disable gridlines
        mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

        //If set to true, pinch-zooming is enabled. If disabled, x- and y-axis can be zoomed separately.
        mChart.setPinchZoom(true);

        //alternative BackgroundColor
        mChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

        //working on data
        LineData dat1= new LineData();
        dat1.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        //add data to line chart
        mChart.setData(dat1);



        //get Legend object
        //By default, all chart types support legends and will automatically
        // generate and draw a legend after setting data for the chart. The Legend usually consists of
        // multiple entries each represented by a label an a form/shape.
        Legend Legend1= mChart.getLegend();

        //customize legend

        Legend1.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.LINE);
        Legend1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        XAxis x1=mChart.getXAxis();
        x1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        x1.setDrawGridLines(false);

        // if set to true, the chart will avoid that the first and last label entry
        //     * in the chart "clip" off the edge of the chart
        x1.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);

        YAxis y1=mChart.getAxisLeft();
        y1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        y1.setDrawGridLines(false);
        y1.setAxisMaxValue(120f);

        YAxis y2=mChart.getAxisRight();
        y2.setEnabled(false);
    }




}
```

this is my **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nadeesha.sobiga"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-2-2-4 (1).jar')
}
```

i try to build the app like in this video.[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a20EchSQgpw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEoIi.png)

But after certain point it shows **error in the logcat.**

> ```
> 2018-12-27 12:55:57.722 12932-13231/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
> 2018-12-27 12:55:57.723 13649-27886/? E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
> 2018-12-27 12:55:57.732 13649-27886/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status
> ```
>
> -12.
>       2018-12-27 12:55:57.732 13649-27886/? E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
>       2018-12-27 12:55:57.732 13649-27886/? I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_started com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.z.c@a009490
>       2018-12-27 12:55:57.739 13649-27886/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded

***please help me*** to solve this problem.

When I try to open the app .it shows like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEoIi.png)

Comment: please any one answer me....i need to do this for my project please anyone help me

Comment: mainLayout equal null 
not declared mainLayout 
remove comment 
//        mainLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);